# Symbol Table in Python

Tags: python, symbol-table

How can we see the Symbol-Table of a python source code?

I mean, Python makes a symbol table for each program before actually running it. So my question is how can I get that symbol-table as output?

Comment: What makes you think python makes a symbol table?

Comment: @WinstonEwert :: http://docs.python.org/library/symtable.html

Comment: Related post for symbol tables maintained by Python at various namespace levels - [What's the difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7969949/465053)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are asking about the symbol table that is used when generating bytecode, take a look at the [`symtable`](http://docs.python.org/library/symtable.html) module. Also, these two articles by Eli Bendersky are fascinating, and very detailed:

[Python Internals: Symbol tables, part 1](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/)

[Python Internals: Symbol tables, part 2](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/20/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-2/)

In part 2, he details a function that can print out a description of a symtable, but it seems to have been written for Python 3. Here's a version for Python 2.x:

```
def describe_symtable(st, recursive=True, indent=0):
    def print_d(s, *args):
            prefix = ' ' *indent
            print prefix + s + ' ' + ' '.join(args)

    print_d('Symtable: type=%s, id=%s, name=%s' % (
            st.get_type(), st.get_id(), st.get_name()))
    print_d('  nested:', str(st.is_nested()))
    print_d('  has children:', str(st.has_children()))
    print_d('  identifiers:', str(list(st.get_identifiers())))

    if recursive:
            for child_st in st.get_children():
                    describe_symtable(child_st, recursive, indent + 5)
```

Answer (score 11):

Python is dynamic rather than static in nature.  Rather than a symbol table as in compiled object code, the virtual machine has an addressible namespace for your variables.

The `dir()` or `dir(module)` function returns the effective namespace at that point in the code.  It's mainly used in the interactive interpreter but can be used by code as well.  It returns a list of strings, each of which is a variable with some value.

The `globals()` function returns a dictionary of variable names to variable values, where the variable names are considered global in scope at that moment.

The `locals()` function returns a dictionary of variable names to variable values, where the variable names are considered local in scope at that moment.

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> import base64
>>> dir(base64)
['EMPTYSTRING', 'MAXBINSIZE', 'MAXLINESIZE', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_b32alphabet', '_b32rev', '_b32tab', '_translate', '_translation', '_x', 'b16decode', 'b16encode', 'b32decode', 'b32encode', 'b64decode', 'b64encode', 'binascii', 'decode', 'decodestring', 'encode', 'encodestring', 'k', 're', 'standard_b64decode', 'standard_b64encode', 'struct', 'test', 'test1', 'urlsafe_b64decode', 'urlsafe_b64encode', 'v']
```

Comment: @voithos He asked specifically about Python source code.  I have not used that module but I believe it is for accessing VM internals or C extension internals, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @voithos But maybe he really meant VM internals.  I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Not sure what happened here, but symbol tables are actually a crucial resource for CPython's compiler, and the "dynamicity" of the language has nothing to do with the topic at hand. This answer is talking past the OP's question.

Comment: Earlier comments to that effect have been now cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Python does not make a symbol table before the program is executed. In fact, types and functions can be (and is normally) defined during the execution.

You may be interested in reading [Why compile Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471191/why-compile-python-code)

Also see the detailed answer by @wberry

Comment: This is top-to-bottom false. CPython's compiler does create a list of symbols, with their scopes. It is done before the bytecode is even generated.

Answer (score 3):

You will likely enjoy Eli Bendersky's write up on the topic [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/)

In CPython, you have the `symtable` module available to you.

In [part 2](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/20/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-2/), Eli describes a method which walks the symbol table that is incredibly helpful:

```
def describe_symtable(st, recursive=True, indent=0):
    def print_d(s, *args):
        prefix = ' ' * indent
        print(prefix + s, *args)

    assert isinstance(st, symtable.SymbolTable)
    print_d('Symtable: type=%s, id=%s, name=%s' % (
                st.get_type(), st.get_id(), st.get_name()))
    print_d('  nested:', st.is_nested())
    print_d('  has children:', st.has_children())
    print_d('  identifiers:', list(st.get_identifiers()))

    if recursive:
        for child_st in st.get_children():
            describe_symtable(child_st, recursive, indent + 5)
```

Comment: Note that `describe_symtable` seems to have been written for Python3.