# variable names based on a parsed string

Tags: string, python-3.x, variable-assignment, naming-conventions, symbol-table

I want to name my variable based on a parsed in string.

For example:
 if parsed in string == 'dog':
           my variable name should be equal to dog and its value the string 'dog'

Comment: You can do this in PHP (they're called variable variables) but I've never heard of it in Python. Maybe do a search for that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085562/923794) to inform about symbol tables in python helps to directly answer the question:

```
>>> varname = 'spam'
>>> value = 'eggs'
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'varname': 'spam', 'value': 'eggs', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> locals()[varname] = value
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'varname': 'spam', 'spam': 'eggs', 'value': 'eggs', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> print(spam)
some value
```

`locals()` provides a `dict` of the locally visible variables. And by modifying the dict, you can change and create new variables. [Python documentation here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/library/functions.html#locals)

There is also a corresponding [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/library/functions.html#globals) to access the globally visible variables. Refer to [this part of the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/reference/executionmodel.html#index-795) to learn about the scope of variables.

In the above context `globals()` yields a `dict` with the same content because in this case the local scope is the global. Inside a class, you'll see different content and you have to decide if you want to mangle the local scope or the global one.

However, it is probably not such a good idea to do this kind of stuff unless you know what you are doing. You could create objects of a self-defined class which have a name attribute - depends on what you intend to do