# Where does a mutable object argument of a function lives? Is there a symbol table? (Python tutorial 4.7.1)

Tags: python, mutable, function-declaration, default-arguments, symbol-table

Going through the [python tutorial, in section 4.7.1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values), a mutable default argument is stored somewhere but I can't seem to find it using `dir()`, `globals()`, `locals()` or `f.__dict__`. I'm referring to this code:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

behaves as:

```
>>> print(f(1))
[1]
>>> print(f(2))
[1, 2]
>>> print(f(3))
[1, 2, 3]
```

I would expect to see this in the namespace of the function, say when I do `dir(f)` but it is not there.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085450/symbol-table-in-python#9085562) but this is way more than I'm probably looking for.

Comment: Why do you want to know (because you generally shouldn't be doing this anyway)?

Comment: ... it's in the `f.__defaults__`, just saw it

Comment: @martineau yeah, it's pure curiosity and looking to gain a bit of insight in the language internals

Comment: Take note that ``f.__defaults__`` is only where defaults can be *accessed*. Various python implementations *store* function defaults in optimised data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> `__defaults__`  A tuple containing default argument values for those arguments that have defaults, or None if no arguments have a default value

```
>>> def foo(a=[]):
...    a.append(1)
...
... foo()
... foo.__defaults__
([1],)
```

There is also `__kwdefaults__` for keyword-only arguments.

```
>>> def foo(a=1, *, b=2):
...     pass
...
... foo.__defaults__, foo.__kwdefaults__
((1,), {'b': 2})
```

---

Note that things in Python are not necessarily stored anywhere *accessible*. For example, the reference count of an object is not available as an attribute. It only exists in the C layer of the CPython *implementation* and requires [builtin magic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) to access.

In fact, `__defaults__` is not a "real" attribute either. It is a builtin property fetching the defaults from wherever the implementation stores them.

```
# python3
>>> type(foo).__defaults__
<attribute '__defaults__' of 'function' objects>
# pypy3
>>>> type(foo).__defaults__
<getset_descriptor object at 0x00000001110adc98>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's in `f.__defaults__`:

```
>>> def f(a, L=[]):
...     L.append(a)
...     return L
...
>>> f.__defaults__
([],)
```

You didn't find `__defaults__` in `__dict__` because it's not stored in the `__dict__`; it's stored in a [dedicated C-level struct member](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Include/funcobject.h#L25), which is mapped to the `__defaults__` attribute by a descriptor on the function type.

Comment: Or `__kwdefaults__` if it's kw-only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spyder, when you type `f.`, autocomplete options should pop up. One of them is `__defaults__`, which holds the defaults.