# Output doesn't change after deleting b/__init__.py and creating b.py with different code?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, filesystems

I create `a.py` and `b/__init__.py`:

```
    $ ls
    $ cat > a.py
    import b
    print "a"
    $ mkdir b
    $ cat > b/__init__.py
    print "b"
```

It works as expected:

```
    $ python a.py 
    b
    a
```

I remove `b/__init__.py` and create `b.py` in the top folder:

```
    $ rm b/__init__.py
    $ cat > b.py
    print "new b"
    $ python a.py 
    b
    a
```

It doesn't print "new b", instead it still prints "b". Why?

Comment: do you still have `.pyc` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just removed `b/__init__.py` but there sure is a `b/__init__.pyc` and in your `a.py` you're still importing b (`import b`). This may be causing the interpreter to assume is already bytecompiled because it sees `b/__init__.pyc` and take this which makes it print the same order.

Note that this command `rm b/__init__.py` just removed the file, not the folder nor the `.pyc`. That might be the reason.

Try `rm -r b` and your code should work as expected.

This is indeed the expected behavior with the python interpreter. If you don't want the interpreter to byte-compile files you can [call it with the -B parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files) but this is not recommended for performance issues because [byte-compiled code makes the program runs much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471191/why-compile-python-code).

You can read more about [modules and byte-compiled files  and search paths in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: What? How can I turn this off?

Comment: Just edited the question with more info and links to lead you on. Hope they'll be helpful.