# Bash - How to catch a Python 3 Syntax Error

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I have a headless piece of hardware which can be remotely updated.

The hardware does little more than run a python script at boot.
I'm trying to improve the robustness of this update system.

If I were to update the hardware with a bugged python script (such as a mis-spelt `print` or `return`(it happens!) or missing a colon) then the python interpreter would refuse to run it as it parses the whole script first.

On this 'parse' it would return back a syntax error. How can I catch this and perform a different action?

Comment: you could do `python foo.py 2>&1 | grep "SyntaxError:"` (since return code won't help you there: it's 1 on invalid syntax), rely on `grep` return code, and rely on `PIPESTATUS` for script return code

Comment: I would recommend to use a python linter (pep8) so that you're always sure that you don't have syntax errors

Comment: you could also try to compile your code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471191/why-compile-python-code)

Comment: One idea is to write a script that wraps execution of your boot script (with `execfile` or similar), and from there you can catch `SyntaxError`s.  Seems a little hacky to me though.

Comment: Write tests for your code

Comment: Start with fixing your deployment process, and don't waste your time engineering around its deficiencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a wrapper script to catch the `SyntaxError` using `execfile` like:

```
try:
   execfile('/path/to/script.py')
except SyntaxError:
   # do the other thing
```