# how to Import python modules once then use modules in python script continusly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that imports modules and that modules are importing top level modules this process takes long period of time, over 5 seconds.
Is there a way in python to import modules once and reuse it for several times?
Is it possible to avoid re importing python modules when you exit your script and rerun your script again?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: @Aran-Fey is a way to run a python script like service and this python script gets some argument  and returns output

Comment: You could create a loop that does what you want and maybe require a keypress each time. Really depends what your script is doing.

Comment: @FrederikHøjlund  how i can run my python script that takes a an argument as http POST and returns it to caller

Comment: You could take a look at Pythons HTTP Server: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: @FrederikHøjlund http.server is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks .

Comment: This may point into an interesting direction for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471191/why-compile-python-code

Comment: You will have to put the path to the modules into your environmental variables path